# merge a column with one cell that rowspans other rows with foreach loop

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table

I have a table whose records are populated with result from database and foreach loop is used.
I want few columns with a single cell value to be merged with other columns.
Like:

```
Leave Type | Max Days | Leave Taken | Leave Balance | Roll Over
Float      | 3        | 2           | 1             | 
Personal   | 3        | 2           | 1             |   5
Sick       | 3        | 2           | 1             | 
Mourning   | 3        | 2           | 1             |
```

First four records are populated using foreach loop, and I need to separately calculate the fifth column and append it.

Here's my HTML:

```
     <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="leave_balance_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Leave Type</th>
                <th>Max Days</th>
                <th>Leave Taken</th>
                <th>Leave Balance</th>
                <th>Roll Over</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $totalLeaveTaken = 0.00;
        $totalBalance = 0.00;
        $totalRows = count($GetEmployeeLeaveBalance);
            foreach ($GetEmployeeLeaveBalance as $member):
                $totalLeaveTaken += $member['usedDays'];
                $totalBalance += $member['Remaining_Leave_Days'];
                $leaveBalance = floatval($member['Remaining_Leave_Days']);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $member['title']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['maxDays']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['usedDays']; ?></td>
                <!-- <td><?php echo gettype($leaveBalance);?></td> -->
                <td
                <?= 
                ($leaveBalance < 0) ? 
                "style='background-color:red;font-weight:bold;color:white;'" : ""
                ?>
                >
                <?php echo $member['Remaining_Leave_Days']; ?>    
                </td>
                <!-- <td rowspan="<?= $totalRows; ?>">Some computed value</td> -->
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="background-color: #33CCFF; font-weight: bold;">Total: <?php echo number_format($totalLeaveTaken, 2); ?></td>
            <td style="background-color: #33CCFF; font-weight: bold;">Total: <?php echo 
            number_format($totalBalance, 2); ?></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How do I get the fifth column out of foreach loop and append it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a flag which can help you check if you have already printed the last column as shown below:

```
$totalLeaveTaken = 0.00;
$totalBalance = 0.00;
$totalRows = count($GetEmployeeLeaveBalance);
$lastColumnPrinted = false; //Add This
    foreach ($GetEmployeeLeaveBalance as $member):
            $totalLeaveTaken += $member['usedDays'];
            $totalBalance += $member['Remaining_Leave_Days'];
            $leaveBalance = floatval($member['Remaining_Leave_Days']);
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $member['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member['maxDays']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member['usedDays']; ?></td>
            <!-- <td><?php echo gettype($leaveBalance);?></td> -->
            <td
            <?= 
            ($leaveBalance < 0) ? 
            "style='background-color:red;font-weight:bold;color:white;'" : ""
            ?>
            >
            <?php echo $member['Remaining_Leave_Days']; ?>    
            </td>

            <!--Add The Line Below -->
            <?php if($lastColumnPrinted == false): $lastColumnPrinted = true;?>
              <td rowspan="<?= $totalRows; ?>">Some computed value</td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: dont mention it bro :D